# WCF method sending POST instead of GET

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, api, rest

I'm trying to create a WCF client that accesses a REST API. The API requires that a GET be used for a certain call, so I'm using the [WebGet] attribute for the method. However when I call the method, the actual call that is produced is a POST (viewed by using Fiddler). My contract is as below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/statuses/public_timeline.json",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Status> PublicTimeline();
```

I've also tried using [WebInvoke] with a method of GET but with no success.

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried using a browser to perform the GET?

Comment: Yup. Also, when using POST, the response I get from the server is a 400 error with some text stating that I should be using GET instead of POST.

Comment: The response I get back from the server when using WCF is {"request":"/statuses/public_timeline.json","error":"This method requires a GET."}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using a WCF service to do some work and then call another WCF service. It was the second service that had the issue mentioned above. The problem turned out to be how the first service was implemented.

Solution is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/03a2b109-c400-49d4-891e-03871ae0d083/#416d8cbc-b855-46aa-8a6d-5d6b09db97b6