# WCF call returning 404

Tags: c#, wcf

So I have a WCF service that calls another WCF service.  I'm trying to debug the first service, so I attempted to run it.  It fails with a

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://<host>/ConfigurationService/ConfigurationService.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The inner exception is

> {"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}

Reference:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConfigurationService/GetGlobalConfigurationGroup", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConfigurationService/GetGlobalConfigurationGroupResponse")]
ConfigurationGroup GetGlobalConfigurationGroup();
```

Taking that exact endpoint and putting it in a browser works.  Taking it and putting it in WCFTestClient works.  This code is already running in production, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I debug into the call and I see it's being sent as a POST instead of a GET.   <s>I'm assuming that's the culprit, but I have no idea on how to fix it or why it's magically different.  I've looked at [WCF method sending POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073043/wcf-method-sending-post-instead-of-get) and the link in that answer, but I don't understand it, couldn't get it to work, and the class that extends it is a generated class and won't debug into it either.</s>

I put on failure request logging on the Configuration service, which logs something if I go to a bad location (ConfigurationService.svc1) but not when calling this.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://<host>/SecurityService/SecurityService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="defaultHttpBinding" contract="Service.ISecurityService"
          name="SecurityService" />
      <endpoint address="http://<host>/ConfigurationService/ConfigurationService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="defaultHttpBinding" contract="Service.IConfigurationService"
        name="ConfigurationService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Config for Configuration Service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="ConfigurationService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultHttpBinding"
                  contract="IConfigurationService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="20971520"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Edit: I've noticed that it only exhibits this behavior when running a web project.

Comment: What WCF binding are you using? (basicHttpBinding, WsHttpBinding, WebHttpBinding)?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Added the config line to the post

Comment: Basichttpbinding is a SOAP binding and SOAP always uses POST.

Comment: Can you post the server side configuration for the second service as well as the client side config.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin Added the service config

Comment: which method on the service are you trying to call?

Comment: @lockstock GetGlobalConfigurationGroup

Comment: If it helps, I turned on failure tracing on the Configuration webservice and if I force a 404 by navigating to (e.g.) ConfigurationService.svc1, I get an entry.  But if I call it with the webservice, I still get nothing.  Tried it also directly to the IP.

Comment: Your protocol mapping is HTTPS "<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />" but your endpoints are HTTP?

Comment: @robs that binding is available, but it's not the one they're using...

Comment: Ah yes, quite right - a bit of config hubris

Comment: Do you have host headers, multiple IP addresses or using impersonation somewhere? I had weird problems calling impersonated SharePoint services from the impersonated WCF service, where SP services were on the machine with multiple IPs and host headers.

Comment: @Tom The IP is defined in the hosts file, so I know there are not multiple IP addresses involved.  Not using host headers.  Not using impersonation anywhere.

Comment: How are you sending the request for your debug session?

Comment: What happens if you remove your defaultBehavior (on the client) completely? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Data Contracts in the service that you are trying to call.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here a brief explanation about what they are and how they works.

I think that this is the error because of your error 'OperationContractAttribute'

Maybe is only the ServiceContract.

I hope this helps

Comment: This code is already running in production, and the service is making a call to the endpoint (which is responding to WCFTestClient)

Comment: Oh.. then the problem is only that you can't debug it, right?

Comment: The problem is that the call itself is returning a 404 for me, but not when i use WcfTestClient

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-process environment where services are distributed and applications using those services are communicating via WCF, service contracts must be serialize-able. The easiest way to ensure serialization of contract objects is to decorate them with data contracts attributes as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Without proper serialization your services will still work under some conditions and unless you're attached to all your relevant processes while debugging you won't see any error thrown. Even logging will sometimes fail to show anything (or at least anything useful).

This likely isn't a configuration problem since you're using dataContractSerializer. Decorate your service contract classes so they can be serialized over WCF.

Comment: Our classes are already decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`

Comment: Your web app is pointing at the right port for your services right?

Comment: Yes.  Using the same exact URL works in other places (and in production)

Comment: And you're not trying to pass or return anonymous types or linq query results to/from the service? Just POCOs and primitives?

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem. Turns out I had the wrong address for the service in the configuration of my web project.